# In Oracle grant role to a user from within a procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I would like to grant a role to a user from within a procedure.  For example, I'm logged in as jsmith, and from an SQL Window I can go:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'grant some_role to rjones';
```

and it runs successfully.

But if I create a procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_ROLE_GRANTING_PROCEDURE

IS

BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'grant some_role to rjones';

END;
```

When I run the procedure I get the following error:

> ORA-01932: ADMIN option not granted for role 'some_role'

It seems that I need to grant to my procedure the same role-granting ability as user jsmith, but I don't know how to do that.  Also, I created the procedure as jsmith, so execute permissions on the procedure should not be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

By default, procedures in Oracle are created using *definer's rights*. I don't remember off hand all the details, but in the definer's rights mode, the procedure runs with the privileges of the procedure owner, which may not be the same user executing the procedure, and not even necessarily the same as the user that created/compiled the procedure. Also, I believe it ignores the procedure owner's roles. It only has access to the privileges directly granted to the procedure owner.

In your case, I think you want to compile the procedure using *invoker' rights*. In this mode, the procedure uses the privileges of the executing user, and I believe that the roles are also considered.

To use this mode, you just need to add `authid current_user` to the declaration of the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_ROLE_GRANTING_PROCEDURE authid current_user

IS

BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'grant some_role to rjones';

END;
```

For a better and more complete explanation of the 2 modes in which you can execute procedures, have a look here: [Managing Security for Definer's Rights and Invoker's Rights](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/dr_ir.htm#DBSEG99925).

**EDIT**

I'll also add a link to the following article, which I find a bit easier to read: [Invoker Rights Part 1](http://allthingsoracle.com/invoker-rights-part-1/).